# How to test that invalid arguments raise an ArgumentError exception using RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing a RubyGem that can raise an `ArgumentError` if the arguments supplied to its single method are invalid. How can I write a test for this using RSpec?

The example below shows the sort of implementation I have in mind. The `bar` method expects a single boolean argument (`:baz`), the type of which is checked to make sure that it actually is a boolean:

```
module Foo
  def self.bar(options = {})
    baz = options.fetch(:baz, true)
    validate_arguments(baz)
  end

  private
  def self.validate_arguments(baz)
    raise(ArgumentError, ":baz must be a boolean") unless valid_baz?(baz)
  end

  def self.valid_baz?(baz)
    baz.is_a?(TrueClass) || baz.is_a?(FalseClass)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I use something similar to what JHurra posted:

```
it "should raise ArgumentError for arguments that are not boolean" do
  expect{ Foo.validate_arguments(nil) }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
end
```

No need to alias (rspec 1.3).

Comment: Thanks. Does RSpec automatically have access to private methods? My `validate_arguments` method is private.

Comment: The method is not private because it is a class method and the private keyword does only apply to instance methods. Make the methods instance methods or use `private_class_method :mymethodname` to make the class methods private.

Answer (score 3):

```
it "should raise ArgumentError for arguments that are not boolean" do
  lambda{ Foo.validate_arguments(something_non_boolean) }.should raise_error(ArgumentError)
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the original question because I forgot to indicate that the `validate_arguments` and `valid_baz?` methods are private. So I'm doing `lambda{ Foo.bar(:baz => 'a') }.should raise_error(ArgumentError)` which passes. However, the test still passes if I set `:baz` to a boolean in the test - any idea why?

Comment: I like to `alias :running :lambda` in my `spec_helper.rb` so that I can write `running { ... }.should raise_error`.

Comment: @Theo that's some nice sugar, thanks.
@John Topley, Im not sure whats going on. Your code works as expected on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's very important that you throw an exception for non-boolean values, I think it would be more elegant to coerce the value to a boolean, for example with `!!`:

```
baz = !! options.fetch(:baz, true)
```

That way the client code can pass any truthy or falsy value, but you can still be sure that the value you work with is a proper boolean. You could also use the ternary operator (e.g. `baz = options.fetch(:baz, true) ? true : false` if you feel that `!!` is unclear.

Comment: I take your point, but my `validate_arguments` method actually also validates other arguments passed to the method, using more complex validation logic.

Comment: fair enough... but use this for the booleans, it's annoying to use code that checks types in a dynamic language.